# What are XCode 8 Environment Variables to run Intel Threading Building Blocks

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, tbb

I installed the Intel Threading Building Blocks. I am unable to set the environment variables for XCode (lib and include path).

To start with I want to write a simple parallel_for program, I am not able to add even the namespace `tbb` in my program.

Can anyone please help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFrGG.png)

Comment: Maybe this link can help you http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ppls/TBBtutorial.pdf

Comment: If the solution worked, as you said, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats pretty straightforward: best way to install it:

```
brew install tbb
```

Requires [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), which is highly recommended for any Mac user wanting to use various open source tools.

#### Adjust 3 project settings

After that do `brew info tbb` to see the installation directory, in my case

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2017_U7
```

wich results in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2017_U7/include/
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2017_U7/lib/
```

for the respective project settings, `Header Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`.

In `Other Linker Flags` enter `-ltbb` and there you are.

#### Test code example

I´ve verified this example with the aforementioned settings in Xcode 8.3

```
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct mytask {
    mytask(size_t n)
    :_n(n)
    {}
    void operator()() {
        for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i) {}  // Deliberately run slow
        std::cerr << "[" << _n << "]";
    }
    size_t _n;
};

int main(int,char**) {
    
    //tbb::task_scheduler_init init;  // Automatic number of threads
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads());  // Explicit number of threads
    
    std::vector<mytask> tasks;
    for (int i=0;i<1000;++i)
        tasks.push_back(mytask(i));
    
    tbb::parallel_for(
                      tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,tasks.size()),
                      [&tasks](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
                          for (size_t i=r.begin();i<r.end();++i) tasks[i]();
                      }
                      );
    
    std::cerr << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very straight forward and a simple solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this should go in the tbb website